# linux clipboard read/write in C

Tags: linux, clipboard, gnome, kde-plasma

I done lots of googling but I am still unsure on how to proceed.

What's the most common way of reading/write to the clipboard under Linux?  I want both support for Gnome & KDE desktops.

**Updated**: do I take there isn't an easy solution and one must "aggregate" together multiple sources (gnome, kde) in order to craft a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can look at [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip) and see how they have done it.

> It provides an interface to X
>   selections ("the clipboard") from the
>   command line. It can read data from
>   standard in or a file and place it in
>   an X selection for pasting into other
>   X applications. xclip can also print
>   an X selection to standard out, which
>   can then be redirected to a file or
>   another program.

Comment: Your link currently redirects to another site differentiating between windows and unix. No trace of xclip there...

Answer (score 2):

I might be shooting myself in the foot, but this could give you a hint on how to do the clipboard for kde, not sure about Gnome myself but try it, the script is in python and demonstrates how to get/set stuff on the clipboard, via using dcop and klipper, it is on this site [here](http://arminstraub.com/bits-and-bytes/kde-clipboard-on-the-command-line).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Also it might be worth checking out DBUS under Linux, I am more of a Linux CLI junkie so rarely fiddle with a GUI... :)

Comment: Sorry for adding more useless blurb here but here's one using ruby and gnome's gtk clipboard...http://swimminginbits.blogspot.com/2009/05/get-and-set-gnome-clipboard-data-from.html Other than that, hopefully for you, at some stage, the api's will be unified to ease your pain here...