# Is there any platform-independent way to access the clipboard?

Tags: clipboard, libraries

I have a small side project I want to write and have yet to decide on a language.  Ultimately, I want a way to access and/or modify the clipboard in a platform-independent way.

I'd like to learn a new language to do this, preferably something that:

1. I'll learn a lot from.
2. Will look good on my resume.

...and I'm leaning towards a functional language of some kind (Lisp would be ideal).  That said, I might also want to experiment with interfacing C with other languages, so a C library would also be acceptable.  Are there any libraries out there that would do what I'm looking for in a language that meets the above criteria?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800971/linux-clipboard-read-write-in-c  Just on Linux this proves to be challenging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this is to use [Java's clipboard class](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82).  This gives me a pretty wide selection of languages to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

A crossplatform library (like the[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) framework, which would let you implement in C++, Python, Ruby, and several more) would give you a way to implement this is a cross-platform manner...